# Creating a Sentence based on conditions

Tags: python

This is the input Dict,where i derived and generated a sentence

Input

```
indexes={'Laptops':'1','Mob':'2','Cars':'3','Bus':4}
    Notes={
 

   
    'indexs':[1,3],
    'Laptops':[
        "dell","asus","acer"
    ],
    'Mob':[
        "mi","realme"
    ],
   'Bus':[
     "aB"
 
   ],
    'Cars':["Not found"
         ]

}
```

Created a sentence Generator  to Generate a sentence :

```
def SenGen(alpha,beta):
    for a,b in alpha.items():
        for c,d in beta.items():
            if c in a:
                print(f"{a} are ", end="")
                for i, e in enumerate(b):
                    if i == len(b)-1:
                        print(f"and {e}. ", end="")
                    elif i == len(d)-2:
                        print(f"{e} ", end="")
                    else:
                        print(f"{e}, ", end="")
```

with the help of that function i generated a Sentence

```
SenGen(Notes,indexes)
```

output

```
Laptops are dell, asus, and acer. Mob are mi, and realme. Bus are and aB. Cars are and not found.
```

In the above sentence there is only one value in Bus i.e aB but in the generated i have got it as 'bus are and aB' and for cars it generated as "cars are not found"

But Expected output should be like shown below:

```
Laptops are dell, asus, and acer. Mob are mi, and realme. Bus is aB. Cars are not found.
```

**were Bus is aB and cars not not**

Please kindly help with code and how to improvise my code for the Case 1.

Case 2:

```
input indexes={'Laptops':'1','Mob':'2','Cars':'3','Bus':4}

Notes={
    
    'indexs':[1,3],
    'Laptops':[
        "dell","asus","acer"
    ],
    'Mob':[
        "mi","realme"
    ],
   'Bus':[
     "aB"
 
   ],
    'Cars':[
         ]

}
```

In the case 2, i have value of cars is empty and output is shown below

output

```
Laptops are dell, asus, and acer. Mob are mi, and realme. Bus are and aB. Cars are
```

Desired  output:

```
Laptops are dell, asus, and acer. Mob are mi, and realme. Bus is aB. Cars are not found.
```

Please kindly help with code and how to improvise my code for the Case 2.

i have tired tired with following cases:

```
1.if i == len(b)==1:
                            
    print(f" is {e} ", end="")

2.if i == len(b)==0:
                            
    print(f" is {e} ", end="")
3.if i == len(b)<1:
                            
    print(f" is {e} ", end="")
4.if i == len(b)>1:
                            
    print(f" is {e} ", end="")
```

There is no change in my output,my out remained same as below.

```
Laptops are dell, asus, and acer. Mob are mi, and realme. Bus are and aB. Cars are
```

Comment: Please read the tags **before** posting your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you did wrong was you never took into consideration some cases.
Here's a modified version of your function; I put some comments to explain the cases you forgot:

```
def SenGen(alpha,beta):
    for a,b in alpha.items():
        for c,d in beta.items():
            if c in a:
                # in case the value of some key is empty (like Cars in your case)
                if b == []:
                    print(f"{a} are not found.")
                if len(b) > 1:
                    print(f"{a} are ", end="")
                for i, e in enumerate(b):
                    # in case the key has only one value, which might be "Not found" or some other value
                    if len(b) == 1:
                        if "Not found" in b:
                            print(f"{a} are {e}. ", end="")
                        else:
                            print(f"{a} is {e}. ", end = "")
                    # in case the key has more than one value
                    else:
                        if i == len(b)-1:
                            print(f"and {e}. ", end="")
                        elif i == len(d)-2:
                            print(f"{e} ", end="")
                        else:
                            print(f"{e}, ", end="")
```

Comment: I'd also suggest breaking this into several functions, which can be written and tested separately; for instance, formatting `['a', 'b', 'c']` as `'a, b and c'` can be broken off into its own function. As it is, this function has 6 levels of indentation and 6 `if` statements, in some cases crossing at unexpected levels (eg. there's a three-way switch on `b` being `[]` or length 1 or length>1, one of which is separated from the other two).